# Getting min value from a hashmap which stores a object as value

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I want to get the min value from the data in the HashMap for a certain value in a object and if possible without doing a for loop etc. To get that I have currently this:

```
HashMap<String, Country> biggestCountries = new HashMap<String, Country>();
```

As the HashMap. The data I want to compare is stored within the object country and is getable with:

```
country.getArea();
```

Untill now I have tried this to get the min value but I only got it to work when I replaced the object Country with a Integer:

```
Collections.min(biggestCountries.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Does someone maybe know a good way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Comparator` that sorts based on `area` and get the `Entry` from `Map`

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Country>> comp = 
         Comparator.comparing((Entry<String, Country> entry)->entry.getValue().getArea());
```

Using **Collections.min**

```
Collections.min(biggestCountries.entrySet(),comp);
```

Using **stream**

```
Entry<String, Country> entry = biggestCountries.entrySet()
                                               .stream()
                                               .min(comp)
                                               .orElse(null);
```

If you want to get only the `Country`, using **stream**

```
Country minCountry = biggestCountries.values()
                        .stream()
                        .min(Comparator.comparing(Country::getArea))
                        .orElse(null);
```

or using **Collections.min**

```
Country minCountry = Collections.min(biggestCountries.values(),
                           Comparator.comparing(Country::getArea));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this using the values and stream:

```
Country country = biggestCountries.values()
                  .stream()
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getArea()))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(null);
```

This will sort the values by their area ascending and return the first one found or null if there is nothing.

And as others suggested:

```
Country country = biggestCountries.values()
                  .stream()
                  .min(Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getArea()))
                  .orElse(null);
```

Which will return the minimum value found or null.

Comment: Or get directly the min by : `.values().stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Country::getArea)).orElse(null);`

Answer (score 1):

This is the full code to get country with minimum area.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionMinExample {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add(new Country("IN", 25000));
        countries.add(new Country("US", 45000));
        countries.add(new Country("SL", 14000));
        countries.add(new Country("CH", 24000));
        Country minAreaCountry = Collections.min(countries, (c1, c2) -> c1.getArea().compareTo(c2.getArea()));
        System.out.println("Country with minimum Area: "+minAreaCountry.getName());
    }
}

class Country{

    private String name;
    private Integer area;

    public Country(String name, Integer area){
        this.name = name;
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getArea() {
        return area;
    }
    public void setArea(Integer salary) {
        this.area = salary;
    }
}
```